# How to make a folder show the item counts in Finder?

Tags: macos, finder

[image]

how can I make settings to have this visible? I want every folder show the number of items included. On my Mac, the grey bar with 25 is not visible.

How can I get Finder to draw this count on the bar shown in the red circle?

Answer (score 14):

You can see the file count by enabling Status Bar in Finder. To do this, click View -> Show Status Bar on the menu bar, or press Command + /.

[image: Finder window with View menu bar section open and Show Status Bar highlighted]

Comment: no it doesn't work. it doesn't show any number of items

Comment: When you click "Show Status Bar", does a status bar appear at the bottom of Finder? If so, what does it display (if not the item count)?

Comment: I did it! it couldn't be pressed but I created a new folder and followed your steps again. Now it could be pressed! So thanks! yes the numbers of items are shown now!

Comment: Updating for OSX 13 Ventura: the status bar shows a list of folders, beginning with root and up to the current folder. It also shows the number of items in the selected folder, and available disk space. Selecting an individual folder in the status bar opens it, and shows the number of items it contains.